# Some I-frames encoded as P-frames with Media Foundation

Tags: video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I'm using Media foundation for merging two MP4 videos into one. While processing samples and switching to second video segment I send NotifyEndOfSegment and then read it IMFMediaType and set it as input format to IMFSinkWriter. As the result in output video first frame from the second video file is not I-frame but P-frame. This results in some artifacts for several frames (before next I-frame). When I'm skipping setting input format on IMFSinkWriter for second video file everything works fine. But that's only because both video files has almost the same IMFMediaTypes. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is unusual implementation of Media Foundation. I have read that implementation of MP4 from Microsoft does not support changing media type while writing file. May be it is the reason of 'But that's only because both video files has almost the same IMFMediaTypes.'

Comment: Can you give a link where did you read that mp4 doesn't support changing media type?

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake. ON [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763(v=vs.85).aspx) I found - 'Typically the media type is created by an upstream encoder. The encoder can generate a new media type during streaming, through a dynamic format change. For more information, see Dynamic Format Changes.'